# Symfony2 + AngularJS + CORS

Tags: angularjs, symfony, cors

Finally i decide to post that...i feel idiot, to many information and i don't found the answer,

well, the problem is in the CORS, i try to do this in angularJS:

```
  var request = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data
    });
```

url is a server with a symfony doing a JsonResponse(), nothing especial, trying it with POSTMAN it's all fine (so.. server is fine?) but when i try with other web i see in console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

Actually in symfony i have NelmioBundle with that config:

```
nelmio_cors:
   defaults:
      allow_credentials: true
      allow_origin: ['*']
      allow_headers: ['*']
      allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE','OPTIONS']
      max_age: 3600
   paths:
    '^/':
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE','OPTIONS']
        max_age: 3600
```

I'm using LEMP for more information,

Thanks for advance and sorry for my verybad english!

Comment: You have not defined `host` in defaults or path.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have set `allow_credentials: true`. You should also set the relevant HTTP headers in Angular.

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true';
var request = $http.post(path, data, { withCredentials: true });
```

For more information on CORS, see this link on [CORS tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)